# How Do I store and display (automatically) stories that users can submit on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I'm Making a website for a friend where people will submit stories. These will be short stories, presented on the website with a Title, a "by" section, ideally a picture of the author, and finally the story.

Now I've already got the design of the site up, but this is partly because I know how to use HTML and CSS. Though I know a bit of Jquery, Javascript, PHP, and SQL, I'm at a loss for how I should be saving any of the files and displaying them.

Assuming I want the website to automatically take in any stories, what is the best way to go about doing this? Right now, we have a contact form that would connect to our email where the stories can be sent it... is there a better way to do this so we can somehow just approve the story, then save the story somewhere, then have the website grab the story from where all stories are saved, and finally display it on the website?

If there's any hints or things I can look into that would help me accomplish all of this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a database set up already? That would be a big step towards what you want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no quick and simple answer for this.

You need to store user-submitted data somewhere - preferrably a **database**.

You could try to start with an SQL database like SQLite or MySQL.
These databases hold **tables** that can stores values - values your users submitted

Example: Stories Table

```
story_id   |    author    |     img     |    story_text      |
-----------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+
    1      |     john     |   john.jpg  |  I bought candy.   |
    2      |     mary     |   mary.jpg  |  my pony died! :(  |
```

author, img, and story_text would be values sent to the server from an input form on the website.
The server's language (ie, php) would take these values and store them in the database, something like this

```
$st = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO stories_table (author, img, story_text ) values ( 'john', 'john.jpg', 'I bought candy'. )");
$st->execute();
```

Hopefully you can see how the above line would store things in the table i drew above.

Unfortunately It's nothing something that can be answered here. It's something that requires a whole book. (don't forget you also need to use PHP to grab form values that the user inputted), but hopefully this gives you an idea of one of the ways it can be done

For s*** and giggles, here's an inefficient way of doing it without a database - using a text file instead.

*** Step 1 ***
Learn how to grab form values with PHP. Endless tutorials on google.

*** Step 2 ***
In your server, create a file called ***stories.json***.

Then, when a user submits a form, you can use PHP to append values to to stories.json. Let's say i submit a story. stories.json would look like this

```
{
    "author": "sqram",
    "image": "sqram.jpg",
    "story": "Today, I worked."
}
```

Now you have used PHP to store the information in a file, and can retrieve that information however you want. You could ajax it with javascript and show my story. that stories.json file is essentially being a database for you.

I don't recommend doing it this way. In fact, not a single person will. But it's an actual way of doing.

Comment: Ahh okay, that makes sense. I wasn't sure about what to do but I can make the whole form connect to the database instead. Thanks so much!

Comment: PHP grabs the form values (it's easy, you'll see when you google it'), then PHP has hooks (like the one i showed above) to send it to the database. Googling for "php mysql tutorial" will help you immensely.

Comment: It is important to not if you are taking user input, you will need to sanitize the input to make sure that no nasty  code is uploaded to your server or displayed to other users.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is to use PHP and MySQL with a database.  What you want to do is why PHP and MySQL are a thing.

Have a database where the stories are stored, and there will be a column with if the story is approved or not.  If you approve the story then it will display.

(This is just a rough overview of what you'll need to code.)